# Предоставление доступа после авторизации

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал программу авторизации по клавиатурному подчерку WinForm. Как можно сделать, чтобы прога включалась, и пока не авторизуешься, доступа не было к Windows?

Comment: небыло доступа к чему?

Comment: к windows. Только авторизированным пользователям был доступ

Comment: Не проще разобраться с настройками ОС и воспользоваться проверенными средствами? Это не так сложно и гарантированно надежнее самописного решения на .NET

Comment: Проверенными средствами нельзя. Требуется, чтобы моя программа авторизации работала

Comment: Почему конкретно нельзя? Что не так со стандартными средствами? Дополните текст вопроса. Пока это выглядит как незнание возможностей системы и попытку построить велосипед, когда все соседи давно на антигравах. Чем лучше опишите что хотите получить в результате, тем больше вероятность получить ответ. Правильно заданный вопрос содержит 50-90% ответа.

Comment: У меня есть программа авторизации пользователей по клавиатурному почерку. Теперь надо что она давала допуск  в windows.

Comment: Вот это уже ближе к делу. UI на чем сделан? Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/754640/edit), дополните текст вопроса, чтобы можно было не вчитываться в комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос скользкий, на грани вирусо-писательства, поэтому обозначу только нправления дальнейших изысканий, во избежание, так сказать.

По большому счету вам нужна блокировка экранов пользователя, думаю вы уже знаете что их может быть больше одного-двух.

В свойствах формы можно настроить свойство [FormBorderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)`= None`, это уберет с формы шапку и все дополнительные кнопочки, включая кнопку закрытия приложения. Это бывает полезно и в случае, когда нужно окно произвольной, формы. После этого зарыть программу можно либо через диспетчер задач, либо у приложения есть специальная, добавленная вами, кнопка завершения работы.

Если выставить свойство [WindowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx)`= Maximized`, то при отключенной рамке окно будет занимать экран целиком.

С помощью свойства [TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx)`= true` вы сообщаете о своем желании отображать окно вашей программы поверх всех других окон, у которых это свойство выключено.

Как видите, все что я пока описал есть в официальной документации и начать стоило именно с ее изучения.

Теперь сложности, которые придется решить самостоятельно (на некоторые вопросы тут уже были ответы):

- "волшебное" сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> и другие системные сочетания. Нужно как-то их перехватывать, иначе закрыть ваше приложение можно через диспетчер задач, т.к. он открывается поверх любых окон. Пожалуй самая сложная задача, не уверен, что у нее есть полное решение. Перехватить многие сочетания не составит труда, однако будут и сюрпризы.
- У пользователя может быть больше одного экрана. Будет ли ваше окно растянуто на все экраны, зависит от локальных настроек, так что нужно что-то придумать для всех возможных сценариев, например открыть пустое окошко в том же режиме на каждом дополнительном экране.
- Антивирус. Попытка решить перечисленные выше проблемы, может спровоцировать систему безопасности, которая воспримет вашу программу как угрозу и безжалостно удалит не дав даже запуститься.
- Что делать, если злой админ изменил политики так, что софт на всех машинах запускается исключительно по "белому" списку и не добавил ваше приложение в этот список?

Разумеется это только часть проблем, об которые спотыкаешься практически сразу. В принципе, для какой-нибудь курсовой по программированию, должно быть достаточно перечисленного в начале, без глубокого копания в безопасности. Однако для курсовой по безопасности или реального приложения придется сменить и язык, и платформу, и углубиться в изучение систем безопасности Windows. В идеальном варианте, ваше авторизация должна быть не после, а вместо или одновременно с системной, иначе ее можно обойти тем или иным способом, например через безопасный режим запуска.